# Firebase auth to access Aws DynamoDB

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

I've to create a json returning api hosted on aws(aws is must can't use Firebase cloud Functions).

User who have logged in on webapp can only access api.

I've found [Serverless Api with Aws Api Gateway + DynamoDB](https://sanderknape.com/2017/10/creating-a-serverless-api-using-aws-api-gateway-and-dynamodb/) which doesn't use Aws Lambda Functions.

Access can be limited using AWS Cognito which isn't free!

FirebaseAuth is [free!](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) . So my question is how do I use firebase auth to limit access to above api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article [Firebase authentication vs AWS Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40649605/5787099) might be of some help.

You need to set up a custom authorizer:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/
https://blog.novoda.com/custom-authentication-with-amazon-cognito-and-firebase/