# Creating a maintainable authentication system for a React App

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication, react-redux, jwt

I'm creating a React Application that will be used in production for around 12-20 clients starting out, but it may grow in use in the future. This application will need to be maintained by 2 developers without much back-end experience.

We want this to be secure, scalable, and as easy as possible to maintain. In the past we've experimented with creating our own solution using a Node Server serving JWTokens which keep the authentication status throughout the app using Redux. This code gets pretty cumbersome and is difficult to understand for me and our 2 front end developers. We've also experimented with AWS Amplify, but found it somewhat limiting and constrictive.

I just wanted to see what other developers are using for Authentication systems in their production-level apps. Security is pretty important to this application as well, as it will be storing sensitive user data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page :) In general, "what do you use" questions fall under the "opinion" category. There are also two very different questions here ("how should I handle authentication", and "how should we handle storing sensitive user data") that are unrelated, the latter also being quite broad in scope.

Comment: WRT keeping a token around; it shouldn't be overly-complicated. You can store it using Redux and use `connect` to access it in components that need it and/or keep it in a high-level `<Context>` allowing any component access via `useContext`. (There are other solutions as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several API's that can facilitate user authentication fairly easily. The [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) API allows you to authenticate users in a multitude of ways. Including phone sms authentication, email & password, authentication via social media profiles and a few more. I've used this API for years, it does have some setbacks but its great overall.

An alternative would be [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) which provides more or less the same functionality. While AWS Cognito is cheaper than Firebase, I recommend using Firebase as it's easier to use and overall more flexible.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649605/firebase-authentication-vs-aws-cognito) has some great answers detailing the technical differences between both API's